# Force to landscape mode without setting auto rotate

Tags: ios, swift, rotation

I have a simple example:

[image]

One button in the middle of the view. I want to press that button to force landscape mode then press again to force portrait mode, but I don't want it auto rotate. I know if I set `shouldAutorotate -> true`, it will work, but in my case, I don't want auto rotate mode.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isLanscape = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func rotate(_ sender: Any) {
        isLanscape = !isLanscape
        if isLanscape == true {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
            UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        } else {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
            UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        }

    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found solution for this case.

if `shouldAutorotate -> false`, you will never be able to rotate screen, so I did some tricks here.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var isLanscape = false
    var shouldRotate = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func rotate(_ sender: Any) {
        isLanscape = !isLanscape
        shouldRotate = true
        if isLanscape == true {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
            UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        } else {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
            UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        }
        self.shouldRotate = false
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        let orientation = UIDevice.current.value(forKey: "orientation") as! Int
        if (orientation == 1 || orientation == 3) && shouldRotate == true {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return [.portrait, .landscapeRight]
    }
}
```